# Invalid unicode escape in identifier: '\u092e\u0930\u093e'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]
[image]

I am getting the error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayEaC.png) Invalid unicode escape in identifier: '\u092e\u0930\u093e'

Invalid unicode escape in identifier: '\u092e\u0930\u093e' in react native run

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.